# Showing Google Map in android

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I am following this site https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

I have done all the steps. Imported the google-play-services_lib. Done every steps. While running the project, an error occur and says

> Android Library projects cannot be launched

This is how my build path looks [image]

And my project explorer looks like this.

[image]

I checked the IsLibrary checkbox in android target.

[image]

I couldn't find, what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How do you run yout code? If you are using the emulator, you need to choose yout api-level with the google api.

Comment: I'm running in mobile. I used google api only. see my third image

Comment: Then try to unselect the "is Library" under Preferences->Android

Answer (score 0):

I cleared this issue by doing the following.

1. Don't need to import all the sample projects under google play services. Just import maps only.
2. Uncheck is Library in properties.

It work for me.